# How to call codes of a package directly without installing and importing module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry I am a newbie. I have a python package created with one of my colleagues which is not available currently. Now I have to make small changes to module. I don't want to install the module. I want to just call the codes directly. Is there any way to copy files in the same folder and call it directly?

How can I use code of the package with minimal changes in it?

Comment: You can get away without "installing" the package, but you can't not `import` it. Why the restriction against `import`. What are you *really* asking?

Comment: Maybe...copy & paste?

Comment: I don't need to import the package. But How to use a class in another file without importing?

Comment: @user85361 Module importing is for this purpose, i.e. using a class in another file. If for some weird reason, you can't import it, the only way I can come up with to do this is to copy and paste the class definition from that module. (Again, why not simply import that module?)

Comment: If you want to use the class then you have to import the file, how else would python know which methods and other attributes it has?  Why can't you import the file?

Comment: I don't want to install the module. If I can import it by copying locally in the same directory, it is very good for me.

Comment: @user85361 Then how the dependencies get fulfilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use anything defined within another file, you will have to `import` it.

To be able to `import` a module, you do *not* have to install it into the system-wide package directory. Python will look up modules you're trying to `import` on the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable; simply set that to the directory where you have the file:

```
myproject/
   foo.py
   bar.py
```

*foo.py:*

```
import bar

bar.baz()
```

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=myproject
$ python myproject/foo.py
```

This enables Python to find `bar` in the directory `myproject`, outside the system-wide module installation directory.

You can also set up an isolated environment using [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.pypa.io) and install the module there, which will take care of dependencies if it has any.